# mount NAS shared folder subfolders info ubuntu but with a different user and group grants

Tags: mount, fstab

On our network we have Qnap nas server with a IP 10.20.101.91 and on it we have a Midas shared folder.
\10.20.101.11\Midas
under midas folder I we have folderA, folderB and folderC

I need to mount nas shared midas folder to storage folder.

/storage/folderA
/storage/folderB
/storage/folderC

at the end of mount I need to set
folderA chown to www-data:www-data with owner 33 group 33 and 755
folderB chown to www-data:www-data with owner 33 group 33 and 755
folderC chown to midas:midas with owner 104 group 107 and 755

but when the folders owner can't change and it shows just root:root

How can I solve this problem?